# Show 3D object with LibGDX in an android project

Tags: android, 3d, libgdx

I have a project in android I need to display 3D objects, researched on the subject and LibGDX seems to me the best way.

I already have the libraries in my project.

```
compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:1.3.1"
```

Does anyone have any practical tutorial on how I could exbir a 3D object using this library?

Comment: First result: https://www.google.com/?#safe=active&q=libgdx+3d

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://xoppa.github.io/blog/loading-models-using-libgdx/) link tells you how to import a model(`.obj`, and `.g3db`) that has texture. You can, but do not have to have texture on your model, and when distributing your game, you should change the extension to `.g3db`. If your texture is upside down, just flip the `.png` file, or whatever your using, and re-run the game. It should be fine now.